# manifest.json causing 500 errors in ASP .NET application

Tags: asp.net, web, manifest, progressive-web-apps

So I added a manifest.json to the application. I am using it to define various icon settings and mobile settings. I gave it a start url of "/", and I've tested it with a start url of "~", "." and simply leaving the property undefined.

The manifest works locally, but when I build it to a QA server I get error 500s on a bunch of javascript files in the bundle, including the VMs that generate the navigation for the app. I've added the JSON mimeMap to the web.config and have done a fair amount of research but I'm coming up blank. Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ~ works with the ASP.NET rendering engine to render relative URLs. This is really limited to the server. Remember the PWA code is decoupled from your server-side code/server. The browser is only looking at the server via HTTP and is unaware of any server-side logic you may have. It only cares about what is sent to it across the wire.
Analyze your network waterfall and see what URLs are being requested. If the URLs being requested have the ~ in them, you need to change your manifest file, well you should remove that anyway IMO.
Do you know the details of the server side error(s)? Or are you masking that behind the default 5xx message in ASP.NET? It would be helpful to know what the exact error being thrown on the server is to help debug the issue.

Comment: Sorry for such a late vote. It didn't end up being the answer I was looking for (due to my own lack of provided information), but there's useful info here so take my upvote.

Comment: can you provide more detail on how you solved the issue? Was it a mime/type issue? Or was it something to do with the server-side ~?

Comment: The short of it was our system wasn't configured for service workers. I don't have a long answer because in the interest of time we decided not to use a manifest.

Comment: The web manifest file and service worker are independent of the other. So I am confused about that. Also you system not configured for service workers? Does that mean your web server can server JavaScript files?